# What is the order browsers load files into the cache by default?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, cross-browser

Just curious. would it be based on the file names, byte code etc?
I'm assuming it may be different for some browsers.

thanks

Comment: What do you mean the "order"?

Comment: Your design should probably not rely on this.

Comment: @Marcin maybe he is just curious :D

Answer (score 1):

Open Chrome, Dev Tools, and look at the Timeline. That will give you all the info you need.

Comment: Kind of a stupid question, I literally did this 2 seconds after asking the question! Thanks still

Answer (score 0):

And also FireBug extension of Firefox ( Net Tab ) can give you the same information.